# GPO managed firewall exception not applying to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I have a group policy managed exception for Windows Firewall File and Printer sharing enabled for our subnet, as shown here:

[image: GPO]

This works fine for all of our Windows XP machines. However, when the policy is applied to Windows 7 machines, it doesn't allow ping requests. File sharing including accessing through hidden shares (c$) appears to work with the GPO enabled.

What happens is that a second unchecked exception for File and Printer sharing appears, as seen here:
[image: Win7]

I can't seem to figure out why Windows 7 doesn't recognize and use the GPO exception, and my google skills are failing me.

Since we can enable the ICMP GPO exception, and File Sharing does appear to work, this isn't a high priority issue, but more of a curiosity.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: So you're saying you want to know why you can ping your Windows boxes but not the windows 7 ones? File sharing itself actually works on both? I just want to make sure that I'm reading this correctly.

Comment: File sharing works on both, but the Windows 7 machines add that extra unchecked exception for File and Printer Sharing. With the existing GPO ping doesn't work to the Windows 7 boxes, but if I check the extra "File and Printer Sharing" exception, it does work.

I'd like to know why Windows 7 creates that extra unchecked exception, instead of accepting the existing GPO, and why the existing GPO won't allow pings even though it does for WXP boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 actually uses a different GPO setting for its firewall.

Edit the group policy from a Server2008/Vista/Windows 7 computer. You cannot edit this group policy from server 2003 or XP. If you do not have a 2008 server, use a Vista or 7 machine. You can install Group Policy Management Console on Windows 7 and Vista by installing RSAT from the Microsoft download center then adding GPMC through Programs and Features.

Once you have the policy open, you'll find the correct configuration under Computer Configuration/Policies/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Windows Firewall with Advanced Security. Create a new inbound rule using the predefined File and Printer Sharing.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I've applied this and it appears to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using admx files created since Win7 came out?

You can get them from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d (the Remote Server Admin Tools for Win7)